# getDatabase called recursively using Room

Tags: android, persistence, android-room

I am getting an error when I try initialize my database. I am using Android Room and I want use the RoomDatabaseBuilder to execute the callback and fill my database.

I execute getDatabase method in my Activity class, but then I use the dao to get info from database and the app crashes. It is my first contact with Android Room maybe I am forgeting some important to do. Any can help me with this?

Database Class:

```
static RoomDatabase.Callback rdc = new RoomDatabase.Callback() {

    @Override
    public void onOpen(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onOpen(db);
        Log.d(TAG, "Debug: onOpen");

        //Borramos todos los sonidos de la base de datos
        INSTANCE.soundsDao().deleteAllSounds(); // Instance is "private static DatabaseSounds INSTANCE;"
```

Activity line source of crash:

```
db = DatabaseSounds.getDatabase(getApplicationContext());
   AsyncTask task = new LoadGridAsyncTask().execute(); **

   private class LoadGridAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            //Extraemos el listado de sonidos y los convertimos a DTO
            List<EntitySounds> listSounds = db.soundsDao().getAll(); **** THIS is the line of crash
```

This is the error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:325)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getDatabase called recursively
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:203)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
        at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:96)
        at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:54)
        at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.compileStatement(RoomDatabase.java:244)
        at android.arch.persistence.room.SharedSQLiteStatement.createNewStatement(SharedSQLiteStatement.java:65)
        at android.arch.persistence.room.SharedSQLiteStatement.getStmt(SharedSQLiteStatement.java:72)
        at android.arch.persistence.room.SharedSQLiteStatement.acquire(SharedSQLiteStatement.java:87)
        at com.genaut.myapp.database.dao.DaoSounds_Impl.deleteAllSounds(DaoSounds_Impl.java:140)
        at com.genaut.myapp.database.DatabaseSounds$1.onOpen(DatabaseSounds.java:57)
        at com.genaut.myapp.database.DatabaseSounds_Impl$1.onOpen(DatabaseSounds_Impl.java:65)
        at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomOpenHelper.onOpen(RoomOpenHelper.java:111)
        at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.onOpen(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:149)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:266)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
        at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:96)
        at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:54)
        at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:233)
        at com.genaut.myapp.database.dao.DaoSounds_Impl.getAll(DaoSounds_Impl.java:155)
        at com.genaut.myapp.Home$LoadGridAsyncTask.doInBackground(Home.java:83)
        at com.genaut.myapp.Home$LoadGridAsyncTask.doInBackground(Home.java:78)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

This is the Dao method:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM entitysounds")
    List<EntitySounds> getAll();
```

Comment: move your INSTANCE.soundsDao().deleteAllSounds(); from onOpen to onCreate. See if that works.

Answer (score 8):

> but then I use the dao to get info from database

That will not work, as Room is not set up yet. Either:

- Do this work outside of the `RoomDatabase.Callback`, or
- Do not use Room inside of the `RoomDatabase.Callback`, but instead use the `SupportSQLiteDatabase` that is supplied as a parameter to `onOpen()` and the other callback methods

Comment: @Mark sir, Can I Use room inside onCreate() of RoomDatabase.Callback for inserting data from Local JSON file to DB basically on another thread because calling directly from onCreate() throws Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getDatabase called recursively

Comment: @RahulMatte: No, sorry. You have to use the supplied `SupportSQLiteDatabase` and its API. Alternatively, get your server (or whatever) to give you a starter SQLite database, and then you can teach the `RoomDatabase.Builder` to start with that, and you can skip the inserts in `onCreate()`.

Comment: Need help here -- > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76631243/nested-entity-relation-in-room-database

Answer (score 6):

This happens because `onOpen()` of the callback is called when there's already a `getDatabase` called.

Then with line `INSTANCE.soundsDao().deleteAllSounds()`, if you look in the implementation of `deleteAllSounds()` in `SoundsDao_Impl` (Impl generated file of `Dao`s) , you can see it calls `__db.beginTransaction()` which will call `mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase()`.

This is where the `Exception` is thrown `getDatabase called recursively`.

The fix can be put `INSTANCE.soundsDao().deleteAllSounds()` in another thread like in this reference: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/7-pro-tips-for-room-fbadea4bfbd1

```
ioThread {
    INSTANCE.soundsDao().deleteAllSounds()
}

...

private val IO_EXECUTOR = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

/**
 * Utility method to run blocks on a dedicated background thread, used for io/database work.
 */
fun ioThread(f : () -> Unit) {
    IO_EXECUTOR.execute(f)
}
```

Reference here: https://gist.github.com/florina-muntenescu/697e543652b03d3d2a06703f5d6b44b5

Answer (score 2):

run it in a new separate thread

```
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute {
    INSTANCE.soundsDao().deleteAllSounds(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My friend, I had a similar issue. but for me, the problem was that I get the database from two different classes. When deleted the second initialization from second class it worked.